# Oracle 10 trigger logical

Tags: sql, oracle, date, triggers

I am creating a database of films, where you can insert Films(id, director,the year of publishing-integer...), Directors, Actors(id, fate of birth, date of death-dates)... I have a problem with triggers in it, because in the table actors i want to ensure, that when you you want to add a new actor his year of birth cannot be bigger that the year of film publishing. But with the trigger I have written, i cannot insert any new actor, because the date of birth cannot be compared to the films publishing year, because the film does not exist yet. And i cannot add any new film too, because i have the same trigger on directors-which is not working too, and the film has a foreign mandatory key-id director. It is a bit complicated, so I hope you will get what I mean

```
create or replace 
trigger "XVIKD00"."DATUM_NARODENIA_HEREC" 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
  ON HERCI
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  l_ROK_VYDANIA filmy.ROK_VYD%TYPE;
BEGIN 
  SELECT FILMY.ROK_VYD
    INTO l_ROK_VYDANIA 
    FROM FILMY
   WHERE FILMY.ID_FILM = :new.ID_HEREC;

  IF( (:new.dat_umr_her is not null)  and( FILMY.ROK_VYD is not null)
  extract( year from :new.dat_nar_her ) > l_ROK_VYDANIA ) 
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2009,'Dátumy nie su v správnom časovom 
slede'); 
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Your question is unintelligible.

Comment: I have thought so... I hope i can explain better: i cannot enter any new herec(actor) to my database, because the trigger controlles if the date of birth(dat_nar_her) is smaller number than the year of the film´s publishment(1_rok_vydania), so i need to resolve that you can enter a new actor(herec) eve when he does not play  in any film(1_rok_vydania) is null

Comment: Post everything of your question in English if you really want help. It is very hard to reason about variables/tables/columns not being in english.

Comment: create or replace 
trigger "XVIKD00"."DATE_OF_BIRTH_ACTOR" 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
  ON ACTORS
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  l_YEAR_OFPUBLISHMENT filmy.YEAR_PUB%TYPE;
BEGIN 
  SELECT FILMY.YEAR_PUB
    INTO  l_YEAR_OFPUBLISHMENT
    FROM FILMY
   WHERE FILMY.ID_FILM = :new.ID_ACTOR;

  IF( ( l_YEAR_OFPUBLISHMENT is not null) and
  extract( year from :new.dat_of_birth ) > l_ROK_VYDANIA ) 
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2009,'Dates are not in chronological order'); 
  END IF;
END;                                              Sorry for using the commnet, i cannot answer my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a circular dependence between your tables, and this way you can't insert any records, because the others don't exist yet.

To handle this in a reasonable fashion you should have:

```
Movies
id
name
Publishing_Year

Director
id
name
birthDate

Actor
id
name
birthDate
```

This way, you can always create each one of those, without having any dependencies from the others.

Then when you want to say that some Director directed a Movie you would insert into a table like this:

```
movie_director
id
movie_id
director_id
```

When you want to say that some actor stared in a Movie you insert a record in a table like this:

```
movie_actor
id
movie_id
actor_id
```

And if you wanted to validate if the director or the actor is old enough to be in said movie, you would put the triggers that validate that in these two tables.